# find my mouse position. help me

Tags: python, mouse

I have two questions about making mouse position.

I don't know why this code is not working.  This code presents current mouse position, but the problem is `print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)`.  It is not working.  The book said it removes the old position of the mouse, but it did not work.

```
import pyautogui
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit')
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='')
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s1fG.png)

Second, why doesn't it work in pycharm?  I just can try that in the python idle.

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a window with buttons in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108738/how-to-make-a-window-with-buttons-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code with python2:-

```
import pyautogui
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit')
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr)
        print('\b' * len(positionStr))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')
```

It works fine with python 2.7